# How can I hide points in frame?

Tags: plotting, animation

[image]

How I can hide the points ouside of blackbox? I want make a video moving the black box. like this:
https://youtu.be/o5aNBKvay-M

```
StepA = 1;
LimA = 20;
StepB = 4;
LimB = 6;
Raio = 0.5;
EspSetas = 0.01;
Pos1[x_, y_] := -x
Pos2[x_, y_] := y + If[OddQ[(x)], 0, StepB/2]
t = 0;

myring[a_, b_] := 
  Graphics[Rotate[
    Arrow@Table[{-Pos1[a, b] + Raio*Cos[u], 
       Pos2[a, b] + Raio*Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 π + t*2 π/180, 
       2 π/180}], {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]];

myRingSet = 
  Show[Table[myring[a, b], {a, 0, LimA, StepA}, {b, 0, LimB, StepB}]];

IM1 = Show[
  Graphics[{{Red, Opacity[1], 
     Table[Circle[{Pos1[a, b], -Pos2[a, b]}, 0.8*Raio], {a, 0, LimA, 
       StepA}, {b, 0, LimB, StepB}]}, {Thickness[0.01], 
     Table[Arrow[{{Pos1[a, b], -Pos2[a, b]}}], {a, 0, LimA, 
       StepA}, {b, 0, LimB, StepB}]}}], myRingSet, ImageSize -> 1500, 
  BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[0.014], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
  Axes -> False]
```

I want this video: https://youtu.be/1NTKaqW6vpQ
I did this through ImageTrim, I want know if there is a command to plot only the part I want like PlotRange

```
 x = 0;

 While[x < 100,
  IM2 = ImageTrim[IM1, {{0 + x, 0}, {750 + x, 538}}];
  Show[IM2, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, Axes -> False]

   Export["C:\\Users\\Cliente\\Desktop\\Video movimento \
 fluxoides\\Teste2\\" <> ToString[x] <> ".jpg", IM2, 
    ImageResolution -> 200]

  ; x = x + 10]
```

Solution for my code:

```
StepA = 1;
LimA = 22;
StepB = 4;
LimB = 6;
Raio = 0.5;
EspSetas = 0.01;
Pos1[x_, y_] := x
Pos2[x_, y_] := y + If[OddQ[(x)], 0, StepB/2]
t = 1;


 myring[a_, b_] := 
  Graphics[Arrow@
    Table[{Pos1[a, b] + Raio + Raio*Cos[u], 
      Pos2[a, b] + Raio + Raio*Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 
      2 \[Pi] + t*2 \[Pi]/180, 2 \[Pi]/180}]];
  myRingSet = 
  Show[Table[myring[a, b], {a, 0, LimA, StepA}, {b, 0, LimB, StepB}]];

  Temp1 = Graphics[{{Thickness[0.003], Red, Opacity[1], 
     Table[Circle[{Pos1[a, b] + Raio, Pos2[a, b] + Raio}, 
       0.8*Raio], {a, 0, LimA, StepA}, {b, 0, LimB, 
       StepB}]}, {Thickness[0.01], 
     Table[Arrow[{{Pos1[a, b] + Raio, Pos2[a, b] + Raio}}], {a, 0, 
       LimA, StepA}, {b, 0, LimB, StepB}]}}];

  Temp2 = myRingSet;

  IM = Show[{Temp1, Temp2}, BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[0.014], 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, Axes -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {{0 - 0.1 Raio + (2*t/180), 
       20 + 0.1 Raio + (2*t/180)}, {0 - 0.1 Raio, 7 + 0.1 Raio}}, 
    ImageSize -> 1500]
```

Comment: Please edit your code so that it can be run.

Comment: Please take the time to (learn to) format your code.  In your first post, you will find some tips on how to do that.

Comment: Please explain _"I want to make a video with moviment, so I want to put a limit in the frame plot and move the area of the plot."_  better

Comment: Learn how to vote on good answers and questions. Please read the following comment

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please do not sabotage your original question after receiving an answer. Future readers will not understand the context of the original problem and the relevance of the answers. I've rolled the question back to the previous revision. If you have found a good solution to your problem, you can post it as another self-answer. Multiple answers and self-answers are encouraged on the SE network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = Graphics[{Red, Table[Circle[{n, 0}, n/10], {n, 1, 100, 5}]}];
b = Graphics[{Blue, Table[Circle[{n + 1, 0}, n/10], {n, 1, 100, 5}]}];

Manipulate[Show[{r, b}, PlotRange -> {{pr, pr + 20}, {-10, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
           {pr, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: @garej Perhaps you are right. I confess I don't quite understand the OP saying _"I want to calculate all points, but plot in the frame only the black box and then i will move the box to make the moviment"_

Comment: whatever OP means, it is very interesting question per se: how to make an area, not just a mouse pointer, that would get alive when activated. I cannot find a duplicate and up to the moment feel unable to solve it myself (and I also not sure what OP wants :).

Comment: I put a video showing what I want, but with this new model. I did the video variating the plot range but keeping the same dimensions of the frame. Like this PlotRange is {{ x + 0 , x + 20 }, {y + 0 , y + 10}}, exporting each frame, when I make a loop in x since 0 to 20 with step 0.01 I could make a moviment, but I need all points calculated even if they doesn't appear in the frame..

Comment: @JoaoVictorGomesFreire can you clarify the "all points calculated" bit? From your code, it would seem, they *are* calculated, though not rendered, as they are outside of the `PlotRange`.

Comment: Its because I don't know how to hide them in command "Show" I want to calculate points since 0 to 40, but limit the frame only to 0+x to 20+x and then shift with x. 0+x and 20+x are my "PlotRange". I just want know how use command PlotRange in command Show.

Comment: @JoaoVictorGomesFreire I can't see the difference between you video and my code

Comment: I will upload the video I want, 1 sec

Comment: @Dr.belisarius look the video in the question

Comment: @JoaoVictorGomesFreire can you tell me the difference between your new video and my result? I don't see it

Comment: I don't know if it's because of command "Graphics" but when I put the PlotRange in my code, like in yours, the result is a blank plot.

Comment: @JoaoVictorGomesFreire That's because your code is a little mess :). Try this http://pastebin.com/BDVFtGRP